# The Michelson-Morley experiment (fringe shift)

Tags: special-relativity, optics, laser

[image]

What i don't understand about the experiment is why wasn't the first calculated path drift $ds$ enough but they had to rotate the expiriment by 90 degrees and calculate $dx= ds- ds'$? (Where the $ds'$ is the second calculated path drift). If there as a difference between the fringes wasn't the first calculation enought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, if you know the precise positions of the mirrors (down to <1 micrometer), and you know that the arms are aligned to the ether, then you could measure the effect of the ether in a single measurement.

Unfortunately, Michelson and Morley didn’t have the tech to know the first, and they couldn’t know the second in principle. So they did what’s known as a *relative* measurement. By subtracting the fringe measurements for the orthogonal orientations, the mirror position error is eliminated, and the effect of the ether (should it exist) is doubled.